# delete all files except one subfolder and files within

Tags: powershell

Take this example :

- folder1

  - folder1
  - folder2
  - folder3
  - folder4
- folder2

  - folder1
  - folder2
  - folder3
  - folder4
- folder3

  - folder1
  - folder2
  - folder3
  - folder4
- folder4

  - folder1

    - folder1
    - folder2
    - folder3
    - folder4
  - folder2
  - folder3
  - folder4

I want to delete everything except hierarchy and what's under folder4/folder1/folder2/*
like that :

- folder4

  - folder1

    - folder2

      - file1

So I tried :

`((Get-ChildItem ./root/ -recurse | select -ExpandProperty fullname | Resolve-Path -Path {$_} -Relative)-notlike '.\folder4\folder1\folder2*') | Remove-Item -verbose -Recurse`

this deleted everything under root and I don't understand why cause if I display the result of my selection before the Remove-Item I have what I want to delete.

Comment: you could delete all files _except_ the one you want to keep ... and then delete the dirs that are empty.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at some point folder4 and \folder4\folder1\  was deleted and by extension \folder4\folder1\folder2*

My solution was to use the following :

`((Get-ChildItem ./root/ -recurse | select -ExpandProperty fullname | Resolve-Path -Path {$_} -Relative)-notlike '.\root\folder4' -notlike '.\root\folder4\folder1\' -notlike '.\root\folder4\folder1\folder2\*'  ) | Remove-Item -Recurse`

I think it's not the cleanest approach but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to preserve the one path and its files, selecting all directories that aren't part of of the excluded path and piping them to `Remove-Item` is one way:

```
$RelativeExclusionPath = 'folder4\folder1\folder2'
$ExcludePath           = ( Resolve-Path $RelativeExclusionPath ).Path
Get-ChildItem ./root/ -Directroy -Recurse |
   Where { $ExcludePath -notMatch ( [regex]::Escape(( $_.FullName )) } |
Remove-Item -Recurse -ea silent
```

Files in the root would have to be deleted separately.

---

---

If you wanted to preserve the entire folder hierarchy, not just your dexcluded path & its ancestors, use the `-File` parameter to select only files. Then filter those files based on their `DirectoryName` property:

```
$ExcludePath = ( Resolve-Path 'folder4\folder1\folder2' ).Path

Get-ChildItem ./root/ -File -Recurse |
   Where DirectoryName -notLike $ExcludePath |
Remove-Item
```